# How to write an Android.mk for a header-only library?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android.mk

I'd like to use the `import-module` mechanism for all the libraries used by my apps, including a few that are header-only.  Is there any way to do this, or am I limited to directly `include`ing .mk files which specify the include paths and explicitly adding them to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`?